# Using asset images in Apple Watch Complications

Tags: ios, swiftui, watchkit, watchos

I'm currently build a new Apple Watch App, that should support Complications.
But I can't use an asset image in a Complication.

When I use a system image `Image(systemName: "lock")` everything is fine. But when I use an asset `Image("image_name")` it is not displayed.

I tried to copy the image to the WidgetExtension Assets, but this didn't help.

I'm using SwiftUI and WatchOS 9 for this...

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Are the images inside `Assets.xcassets` > `Complication`?

Comment: @l'L'l Yes, in my case the images are ignored even if they are in Assets in a Complication set

Answer (score 1):

Try using a UIImage instead.

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "lock") ?? "fallback")
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: I tried in various ways to load under watchOS a custom image from the asset catalogue using Image("name"), but all failed. To load an UIImage works. This is surely a watchOS bug.

Comment: `Image("name")` now works

Answer (score 1):

Apparently images that are larger than 120px in size are not loaded. Try a smaller image.